# Why can't I add a class to an interface

Tags: c#, interface

I can do this:

```
public interface IConn
{
    bool Check();
}

public class Conn : IConn
{
    public bool Check() { //Method }
}
```

But I can't do this:

```
public class CustomClass { }

public interface IConn
{
    CustomClass CC();
}

public class Conn : IConn
{
    public CustomClass CC = new CustomClass();
}
```

Instead the interface inheritance makes me apply this:

```
public class Conn : IConn
{
    CustomClass IConn.CC()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My aim is to create a reference to `CustomClass` in the interface (for intellisense) and then simply create the instance of this and do work on it in the Conn class.

Is this possible? How can I do this? Why does an interface make a property that is a class into a method?

Comment: `CustomClass CC();` is not a property, it's a method, which is why you have to implement the method in any class implementing `IConn`.

Comment: @Iridium Even if it were a property the code won´t compile, because OP only has a public field in the class.

Comment: `CC` in the interface is a method, the `CC` you tried to declare in the class is a field, you cannot change the type of member and get the compiler to agree to look the other way. You can implement the method as `public CustomClass CC() { return new CustomClass(); }`, you don't need to use explicit interface implementation.

Comment: In your interface `IConn`, you are declaring a function named `CC` that has no parameters and returns an instance of a `CustomClass`.  In your `Conn` class (which you want to implement `IConn`), you are declaring a public field named `CC` of type  `CustomClass`.  That doesn't match up at all.  You should be able to implement `CC` in `Conn` this way: `CustomClass CC() { return new CustomClass(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to add a field to an interface so that all the classes implementing it would need to have that field. Fields are not allowed in interfaces, but properties are. Properties are very similar to fields, and you shouldn't have public fields anyway.

```
public class CustomClass { }

public interface IConn
{
    CustomClass CC { get; set; } // or just "get;"
}

public class Conn : IConn
{
    // I have changed this to a property.
    public CustomClass CC { get; set; } = new CustomClass();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a method instead:

```
public class CustomClass { }

public interface IConn
{
    CustomClass CC();
}

public class Conn : IConn
{
    // this will always return a new instance of CustomClass, which is
    // not the same behaviour as the code in your attempt.
    public CustomClass CC() {
        return new CustomClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sweeper, good explanation and implementation. I was trying to implement a field and couldn't, and didn't realise I could apply a class as a property (Even though I've done it with other classes, I seem to have brain block because it was my own custom class!)

Comment: I tried to accept yours earlier but it wouldn't let me until the timer hit. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have actually two problems:

1. Your interface defines a **method**, so your implementing class also needs a **method** of the exact same name and the exact same parameter-list. What you seem to want is **property** instead a method.
2. Your class has public field, which does not implement *anything*, as it is not allowed for an interface. Actually only methods are allowed for interface. However, as properties are nothing but a set of a get- and set-method created by the compiler, you can also define them on an interface.

So use the following:

```
public interface IConn
{
    CustomClass CC { get; set; }
}

public class Conn : IConn
{
    public CustomClass CC { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "add a class to an interface", though I must observe that I hope I understood what you meant correctly because the sentence doesn't really make any sense.

But let's look at what you did:

```
public class CustomClass { }

public interface IConn
{
    CustomClass CC();
}
```

This declares a class, `CustomClass`, and an interface, `IConn`, and in the interface you declare a method, `CC`, which returns a reference to a `CustomClass` object.

So far so good.

Then you try to implement the interface, and this is where your problems crop up:

```
public class Conn : IConn
{
    public CustomClass CC = new CustomClass();
}
```

Here, the compiler will complain with:

> CS0535 'Conn' does not implement interface member 'IConn.CC()'

The reason for that is that in the interface, `CC` is a **method**, but in the class where you tried to implement the interface, you made `CC` a **field**.

For an interface to be successfully and legally implemented by a class, you must both implement all the members of the interface, and you must implement them using the same type of member.

So if you declare `CC` as a method in the interface, it has to be implemented as a method in the class, there's no getting around that.

So you can just change your class to this:

```
public class Conn : IConn
{
    public CustomClass CC()
    {
        return new CustomClass();
    }
}
```

or, if you're on a newer C# version where you have expression bodied members, you can write it like this:

```
public class Conn : IConn
{
    public CustomClass CC() => new CustomClass();
}
```

This is just a few extra characters away from what you had.

---

Now, what if I misunderstood your question, and you really wanted all implementors of your interface to implement a field? Well, you can't do that.

In an interface you can only declare properties and methods, not fields, not constructors, or other stuff.

---

Now, additionally, you say this:

> Instead the interface inheritance makes me apply this:
>
> ```
> public class Conn : IConn
> {
>     CustomClass IConn.CC()
>     {
>         throw new NotImplementedException();
>     }
> }
> ```

I'm *guessing* that at the time you thought this was the only legal way to implement that method you still had the field in there, because you cannot make a public method **and** a field, both with the same name, this is illegal:

```
public class Conn : IConn
{
    public CustomClass CC = new CustomClass();
    public CustomClass CC() => new CustomClass();
}
```

and you would get this:

> CS0102 The type 'Conn' already contains a definition for 'CC'

However, if you instead make the method explicitly implement the interface, like this, it would compile:

```
public class Conn : IConn
{
    public CustomClass CC = new CustomClass();
    CustomClass IConn.CC() => new CustomClass();
}
```

However, now you have *two* members named `CC`, one only available through the interface, and is likely not what you want.

---

Final guidelines here. If your intention is to *hold* a reference to `CustomClass`, even if that reference is constructed inside the class implementing `IConn`, then you should instead declare and implement `CC` as a property.

However, if your intention is that every time you "read" `CC` (read the property or call the method, depending on how you choose to declare and implement it), you would get a new instance of `CustomClass`, then in my opinion you should stick with the method.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer and explanations - I had phrased my question wrong - I really just wanted my CustomClass as a property BUT with the additional information you've provided I've already learned something new and wondered the implications and how I can apply returning Classes from a method implemented by an interface!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a method in the interface. What you really want is a property

```
public interface IConn
{
   CustomClass CC { get; set }
}
```

Comment: That still doesn´t compile, as the public field doesn´t implement the interface-property.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ah, I read too fast and thought I saw a `=>`. Yeah, well comments already say all there is to say about the issue.

Comment: This was actually more inline with what I was after - a property instead of a method.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit. Please see if that helps-

```
   public class CustomClass {      }

   interface IConn
   {
       CustomClass CC();
   }

   public class Conn : IConn
   {
      public CustomClass CC()
      {
         return  new CustomClass();
      }
   }
```